# Overlapping image inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Question: how 2 images can live in the same td ? how can I overlap the first one?

Bug: the images doesn't overlapping, sometimes the character's image is printed next to the tiles images instead to overlap it.

I will link to you the pen of this little program, try to random generate different times to occur in this bug.

[penHere](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

After the first sections of customization a random map will generate the position of the characters.

I investigate over this bug, and i discover that it's not a problem of coordinates ( they are random generated with this function )

```
function coordinate(){

    let rowCoord= map.length;
    let cellCoord = map[1].length;

    let coord = {
        row: Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCoord),
        cell: Math.floor(Math.random() * cellCoord)
    }

    return coord;  
};

// this function will place the character if the coordinates are ok. Else we have a callback to the same function.

function placeCharAndItem(char){

    let coord = coordinate();
    // with this if you choose a walkable table to spawn, this is random generated
    if(map[coord.row][coord.cell] === 0 ){
        place(coord, char);
    }
    else{
        placeCharAndItem(char);
    }
};
```

The map is random generated too. It's something like this.

```
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
```

and this is the function that let the character image spawn on the right td

```
function place(coord, char){
  var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", char.image).addClass('char');
  var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
  var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
  cell.append(charImage);
};
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put two images in a table cell, they will be displayed one after the other by default, this is just how the HTML works.

To make overlap of two images you can explicitly set position of the second image relative to it's parent table cell. You can do it with CSS:

- Apply `position: relative;` to the parent `td`;
- Apply:

  ```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  ```

  to the second image (and all next images in the same cell, if you will have more).

Keep in mind that second image now will be out of the standard HTML flow, it will no longer affect the cell size, it will overlap anything. You may need to explicitly set the cell size.

Also you can set this styles dynamically with the JQuery:

```
// Get your table cell and image somehow.
const $cell = $(...);
const $image = $(...);

$cell.css('position', 'relative');
$image.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
});
```

Or with a plain JS:

```
const cell = document.querySelector(...);
const image = document.querySelector(...);

cell.style.position = 'relative';
image.style.position = 'absolute';
image.style.top = 0;
image.style.left = 0;
```

Comment: I'm in doubt with my comment ( i'm pretty new with jquery and javascript) but the css is already set on relative and absolute, but the bugs still goes on. 

` 
#tableGame .td {
  position: relative;
}
#tableGame .char {
  position: absolute;
} `

Comment: You can inspect, what actually happens, using a browser developer tools. In most common browsers, this is integrated and usually can be opened by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I. With it you can simply see which styles are applied to which elements actually, and so on. And as I can see in the code pen you posted, there was no `position: relative` on cells. Also, `top` and `left` properties is needed. Without them the image remains in its natural place next to the first image.

Comment: i found the bug in the program, it wasn't a css error. It's the way how the array print the result in the table. I will up the same your answer, because i learn a lot by it :) so thanks for the help.